# Angular2 create dynamic component on param route

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular-components

I have an element that has a `type` property.

```
class Element {
   private id: string;
   private type: string;
   private properties: Map<string, any>;
}
```

the element can have different properties based on type.

I need to create a different form (any type has different fields) on a single edit page.

My idea is to create a different form component per type and load it, into edit page, based on a route parameter "type".

the route can be "/elements/:type/:id/edit"

How can I implement this behavior?

Comment: You can use a similar approach to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36325212/angular-2-dynamic-tabs-with-user-click-chosen-components/36325468#36325468

Comment: what have you tried so far? the angular docs go into depth on dynamic forms and dynamic components both.